# Failed to flash file gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip genymotion

Tags: genymotion

Why am i getting "failed to flash file gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip genymotion" this error when i am trying to install Google apps on Genymotion simulator.

I just drag n dropped >>gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip<< and gave this error.

Please let me know if anyone else has faced the same issue and the fix.

Answer (score 10):

I also faced same issue I sort it by downloading the correct GApps meant for particular android version.Here is the list:

- Google Apps for Android 6.0

  1)  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406 - 
     gapps-L-4-21-15.zip)

  2)  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438 -
      benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 5.1
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406 -
  gapps-L-4-21-15.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 5.0
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559 -
  gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.4.4
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358544845 -
  gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.3
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124 -
  gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.2
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000128 -
  gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 4.1
  (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22979706399755082 -
  gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip)
- Google Apps for Android 2.3.7
  (http://www.mediafire.com/download/bs063kb0m742o5l/gapps-gb-20131027-signed.zip- gapps-gb-20131027-signe.zip)

***Note***:  For Android 6.0 ,you need to flash first .zip i.e(gapps-L-4-21-15.zip)and reboot .Then you need to sign-in to your google account and then flash second .zip (benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip.) and reboot again.

Hope it helps ...Cheers

Comment: you made my day! The last step for M was the problem I had

Comment: @Antonio Happy to know it help..Thanks for appreciating

Comment: this [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en) is helful too

Comment: Thanks for the links. It was a little hard to find those because recent Genymotion itself provides the 'Open GAPPS' button. But it doesn't work with old 4.3 ROMs, so your answer is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Feb-2016**

1. Download and install [GAPPS APK](http://opengapps.org/app/)  from the official website.
2. Grant root permissions to the app and click next
3. This app will **automatically detect CPU Architecture and Android version**. please note it down
4. Then go to [OPEN GAPPS WEBSITE](http://opengapps.org/#downloadsection)
5. And then select desired **`Platform`** , **`Android version`** and **`Variant`** and click download button.
6. After downloading `Gapps.zip` file. Now **Drag and Drop** **GApps.zip** ,  [Genymotion-ARM-Translation](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23252070760974384) one by one then  restart Genymotion.

Answer (score 2):

Completely remove your Virtualbox and Genymotion. There are old registry files hidden in your computer which are preventing you from flashing Gapp properly.

Here are few links teaching you how to uninstall Genymotion and Virtualbox:

[uninstall-genymotion-genymotion-removal-genymotion-windows-uninstaller](http://www.how-to-uninstall-program.com/uninstaller/uninstall-genymotion-genymotion-removal-genymotion-windows-uninstaller.html)
*Don't download their software because it doesn't remove everything*

[how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows](http://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/)

And finally there should be a `Genymobile` folder in your

```
 User -> (Username) -> AppData -> Local folder
```

Hope that helped

Comment: Also try searching "VBox" in your System32 folder to find leftover files. There will be few files in the FileRepository folders that cannot be removed easily. Use http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/67717-take-ownership-file.html is a guide

Comment: What if I'm experiencing this issue on Mac?

Comment: worked for me without running uninstall code on ubuntu 15.10, genymotion 2.6.0
only deleted genymotion and uninstall virtual box on software center

Comment: @Lrrr can you please elaborate? Does removing the Gen and VB and reinstalling them solve the issue? You also pointed out the app data. should that also be removed?

Answer (score 1):

This issues is faced while you put this file in something wrong version of genymotion devices.

[here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) you can get proper guide line for installing the gapps files in genymotion device,

it will be a different for all the version.so might be your file would not suitable for your version, so please follow the guideline

Comment: I am using gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip for android 4.3
here is the guide i am using...
http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps

Comment: and Genymotion version is v2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

That'll happen when you're trying to install flashable gapps meant for a different api version.  Make sure the device you're emulating in genymotion is the version the gapps is meant for.

Follow this guide: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en

Comment: That's a very generic answer, and no explanation. Just points to your blogpost.

Comment: The answer is complete and the guide is helpful.