# Unable to flash open_gapps-arm-6.0-stock-20160220 file in genymotion?

Tags: android, performance, flash, android-emulator, google-play-services

Using playstore apps on genymotion using drag and drop creates a error **`Failed to flash file open_gapps-arm-6.0-stock-20160220.zip`**and  i have tried so many solutions and none worked 
This Previous solutions is also not helpful [Failed to flash file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883892/failed-to-flash-file-gapps-jb-20130813-signed-zip-genymotion)

Here iam using

- Genymotion 2.6.0
- Virtual Box VirtualBox-5.0.14-105127-Win_2
- Emulator Nexus 5X
- API Level 23
- API Version -6

[Screen Shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6bH8.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SO-26883892](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883892/failed-to-flash-file-gapps-jb-20130813-signed-zip-genymotion).

Comment: Yaa but problem is that solution is not woking @gerardnimo

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fix it by downloading `gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip` from https://www.androidfilehost.com.
find `gapps for your android version` from `https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145`