# App doesnt appear in genymotion virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm using genymotion for as virtual device. But when I run virtual device, my app doesn't appear in device. How to fix it?

Comment: May be you dont have graphic card.

Comment: I have notebook with intel hd3000 graphic.

Comment: dont have idea without having a look.

Comment: U can try using android AVD, it's quite faster now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883892/failed-to-flash-file-gapps-jb-20130813-signed-zip-genymotion/42110644#42110644